Estimating Individual-Level Causal Effects Under Selection on Observables
The value of a randomized controlled trial is that the random assignment of treatment ensures that no confounding is biasing the relationship between treatment and outcome and, therefore, a simple difference in the means of outcome between treated and non-treated can be attributed to the causal effect of treatment.
However, this approach is limited to a population-level interpretation, since each groups as a whole represents a counterfactual state of the other group, rather than any individual serving as another individual's counterfactual state.
When we can't do randomization of treatment, a very common identification strategy is selection on observables where we manually identify and adjust for all sources of confounding. This is rightly portrayed as a much weaker identification strategy, but, I have never fully understood why, when operating under selection on observables, we don't focus more often on individual-level causal effects. To me, this seems possible, since we have data on each unit's confounder values. Assuming we have correctly identified and measured all confounders (an assumption that estimating an average population-level also requires), do you not have sufficient information to estimate individual-level causal effects for at least some individuals?
For example, when using exact matching, you can find a unit with the opposite treatment status, but identical confounder values. Assuming you are not extrapolating beyond the support of your data (a problem the average population-level approach also requires), estimating the marginal effect for a given unit should also support the same individual-level causal effect. Assuming there is no unobserved confounding, how are selection on observables approaches like this not able to identify individual-level causal effects?

First we need to distinguish between individual causal effects (ITEs) and conditional average treatment effects (CATEs). Vegetabile (2021) makes this distinction clear. To identify the ITE, you need to know all variables that modify the treatment effect, whether they are confounders or not. For example, in a randomized trial, there are no confounders but plenty of effect modifiers. The average treatment effect (ATE) is identified by the randomization, but you can't estimate the ITEs without measuring all effect modifiers. You intuition, as I understand it, is that in an observational study, we are collecting and adjusting for many more variables than we would have to in a randomized trial, and so we should be able to collect more effect modifiers and therefore be able to identify the ITE.
The problem is that the set of variables required for identification of the ATE in an observational study may not include all effect modifiers. In that case, we can only estimate treatment effects conditional on the variables we collect and adjust for. In many cases, it would inappropriate to adjust for effect modifiers even if they were measured; for example, if an effect modifier is a mediator between treatment and the outcome, adjusting for it would bias the estimate by blocking the effect of treatment.
Instead of estimating the ITE, which is virtually impossible on identification grounds, we often consider the CATE instead, which is the ATE for a given profile of the observed and adjusted-for covariates. For example, we could identify the effect of a medicine on developing a disease for someone with a specific patient profile defined by the pre-treatment covariates measured. This still isn't an ITE because it averages over the distribution of covariates we didn't measure; those covariates may not be required to adjust for confounding (i.e., because they don't affect treatment), but they might modify the treatment effect.
There is a large literature on estimating the CATE and methods for doing so are quite popular already. The most popular methods in the causal inference literature for doing this are Bayesian causal forests (BCF) and causal random forests. Both of these methods use tree-based machine learning models to find covariate combinations that yield different CATEs. This literature is often called the "heterogeneous treatment effect" (HTE) literature because it focuses on characterizing the heterogeneity of CATEs across covariates.
A huge problem that these methods face is that there is very little precision to estimate CATEs. To estimate a CATE fully nonparametrically (i.e., without any assumptions on the data-generating process) requires estimating a treatment effect for each unique combination of covariates. With any continuous covariates or with many categorical ones, it is very unlikely that you will find any pair of units with identical covariates values (i.e., exact matches). Even if you do, it is unlikely that you will have a subsample with a given profile large enough to estimate the CATE for that profile with any precision. Instead, these methods use machine learning to smooth and regularize the CATEs so that information from the whole sample is used to inform estimation of the CATE. When too much information is shared across units, the CATEs approach the ATE, but are estimated with certainty; when too little information is shared across units, heterogeneous CATEs emerge, but they are estimated with so little precision that they are not actionable. Striking the balance between these two is the fundamental goal, but it is also a challenging task. The more data you collect, the less pooling across units is required to estimate heterogeneous CATEs with precision.
A key issue with estimating CATEs is that their estimators are not doubly-robust, which is a quality we like in causal effect estimators. Doubly-robust estimators have a fast rate of convergence, making them asymptotically efficient and allowing for valid normal-theory inference even when using machine learning models. To estimate CATEs using a pooling method, the outcome model needs to be correct. That's why the HTE methods that have become popular use flexible machine learning models. Even if it is possible to estimate an ATE using a simple parametric outcome regression model, that model will not necessarily be able to validly estimate the CATEs.

The biggest problem with an approach that uses "selection on observables where we manually identify and adjust for all sources of confounding" is that unless you assign treatment randomly you can never perfectly adjust on all sources of confounding, or even know how close you have come to this impossible goal. You say that matching or adjusting will get you the true effect "Assuming there is no unobserved confounding." But the whole reason causal inference is so difficult (and why random assignment exists) is because we rarely are comfortable making this assumption.
There are really two distinct problems here.

There is no way to definitively prove that you have identified all possible confounders
Even for a confounder you know about, you can never control for it perfectly because you can never measure it perfectly

Let's say the treatment is participating a job training program, and the outcome is getting a good job. Let's say that one of the confounders is "being a hardworking person:" people who "work harder" are more likely to put in the effort to participate in a job training problem, but also more likely to get a good job  even if they don't participate in the program. To estimate the true effect of the program you need to fully control for this confounder. How could you possibly do that? You could ask people a bunch of questions that you hope will provide a measure of how "hard working" they are, but no measure is perfect, and there is no way to determine precisely how imperfect our particular measure is. No matter how many questions you spend trying to measure "hardworkingness" you will never know if you've fully controlled for the underlying construct that is biasing your casual inference.
And even if we could fully control for "hardworkingness," what about all of the other things that might be confounders. Maybe "thinking that job training programs are worthless" or "extroversion" or "neuroticism" or "math ability" or "proximity to public transportation" or "having a car" or "having a strong social network" could be confounders? And if so, how could we actually go about measuring those things perfectly to fully adjust for them?
Theory can give you a good sense of things that might be confounders, and if you put in a lot of effort you can try to imperfectly measure and control for those things. But there will also be other things out in the world that might matter that we haven't thought of yet.
Random assignment is special because it controls for all possible confounders, even ones we don't know about or can't measure.
That doesn't mean that "controlling for stuff via regression or matching" is worthless. But it explains why random assignment (or other approaches like natural experiments, instrumental variables, or regression discontinuity designs) are generally held to be stronger than just trying to control for individual confounders in a model or something.

Yes, but this critique equally applies to estimating any effect (average or individual-level) under selection on observables. My question was less concerning, "why choose randomization over selection on observables" and more concerned with, "if you're going to go the selection on observables route, why not attempt to estimate individual-level effects since you are trying to identify the adjustment set necessary to construct valid counterfactuals?" Unobserved confounding may always be an issue under SOO, but we still try to estimate causal effects anyways. Why not individual-level effects?
